# Finding product name from UPC/EAN

Tags: barcode, barcode-scanner, google-search-api

Is there any way to get the product name from UPC/EAN barcode scanned from Google API?

Answer (score 1):

There is no general registry of UPC product codes. You can find a list of the country codes at the beginning of the number easily, and with some legwork possibly get the national organization for a few countries that you're particularly interested in to give you a list of their secondary allocations.

But in order to get all the way down to "Banana chips, bag of 200 g, reduced trans fat formulation, Danish/Swedish/Finnish text on packaging" there's only the particular manufacturer to ask. That, or own a supermarket and register the UPC numbers of new items when you start stocking them.

Comment: Heard this can be accomplished by deprecated google base api. Not sure the replacement for this though. Do you have any idea?

Answer (score 1):

Allegedly the `gtin` field holds the UPC/EAN code, if you restrict the search to values in that field you should only get responses where the gtin matches your barcode.

For example if you scanned your barcode and got an EAN-8 code of *05001234* then in the query string of your API call you could set

```
https://www.google.com/search&q=05001234&restrictBy=gtin=05001234
```

I have often seen multiple products returned for a single code so I guess the UPC/EAN are not globally unique or some providers have not been uploading their products under the right code.

In the response from Google are fields which hold the product title and description, you just need to parse the JSON or ATOM response.

Answer (score 0):

I found another API https://market.mashape.com/mignify/gtin2product. It's pretty good. You can get products information from UPC/EAN/GTIN. It can return products description in different language.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Rapid API https://rapidapi.com/search/ean. Here you get lot of API like Amazon API, Google Shopping, Barcode Lookup